# Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_filter() in index.php in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, fatal-error, add-filter

I want to change my wordpress theme dynamically by user browser. So I found this code on the net and added it to my index.php file

```
add_filter('template', 'switch_theme_by_browser');
add_filter('stylesheet', 'switch_theme_by_browser');

function switch_theme_by_browser($theme) {

    $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$browser) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$browser))
    {
        $theme = "twentyeleven";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$browser))
    {
        $theme = "twentyten";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$browser))
    {
        $theme = "Boxoffice";
    }

    return $theme;
}
```

After that it shows me "Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_filter() in /home/xxx/public_html/domain.com/index.php on line 17"

As I undertand the "add_filter()" should be a function that is built in wordpress.

Comment: try adding this to functions.php instead of index.php

Comment: The thing is, it should be the very first thing to be read by the site so it knows what template to load up.

Answer (score 0):

As Dawson said, this needs to go in your `/wp-content/themes/[theme]/functions.php` file.

Comment: ok, now it says:Warning: require(/home/xxx/public_html/domain.net/wp-content/themes/twentyten/inc/theme-options.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xxx/public_html/domain.net/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/functions.php on line 122

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/xxx/public_html/domain.net/wp-content/themes/twentyten/inc/theme-options.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/xxx/public_html/domain.net/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/functions.php on line 122

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress root directory, put `require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/plugin.php' );` before `require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/functions.php' );` in file wp-settings.php.
I verified this solution at http://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-add_filter.