# how to print or get an array that sent from jquery to php file Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, wordpress

I want to send an array generated in jQuery to a php file. I get stuck on this. I tried several way but no luck. I want to echo/print_r the array in php file. Experts give me your kind look. My code is given below :

js:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        url = '<?php echo includes_url().'cs_cause.php'; ?>';
        var allVals = [];
        $('#deleteProduct').click(function(){

            $('.delete-product:checked').each(function() {
                allVals.push($(this).val());
            });
            $.post(url,{ array : allVals }, function(response,status){
                    alert( response+ '  ' + status);
            });
        })
    })
</script>
```

php :

```
<?php
    if($_POST['array'])
    {
        $r = $_POST["array"];
        print_r($r);
    }
?>
```

Comment: so how can I get the array ??

Comment: whats the response by the way? use `console.log(response)`

Comment: pls have a look : http://screencast.com/t/shpt3IpLOI2  @Ghost

Comment: Your url path seems to be wrong mate..Where is your `cs_cause.php` file located

Comment: it is in : wp-content\themes\aidreform\include\cs_cause.php

i would like to mention that , my script and php stuff both are in the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this mate.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        url = "http://localhost/fundraise/wp-content/themes/aidreform/include/cs_cause.php"; 
        var allVals = [];
        $('#deleteProduct').click(function(){

            $('.delete-product:checked').each(function() {
                allVals.push($(this).val());
            });
            $.post(url,{ array : allVals }, function(response,status){
                    alert( response+ '  ' + status);
            });
        })
    })
</script>
```

Incase u move this file to the server change the url to

```
url = "/wp-content/themes/aidreform/include/cs_cause.php";
```

Comment: how u know it is - "localhost/fundraise" ??
now it shows : http://screencast.com/t/RiDSzAXF

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276583/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-add-filter-in-index-php-in-wordpress

Comment: Thank u very much .. I fixed it out .. I just moved my php stuffs into a new file. now its working !! :) .. Thanks a lot. I have question of curiosity that how do u know the name  "localhost/fundraise" ???
and what was the problem when i used "include_url()" ?